# How to avoid exception The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. in .net

Tags: c#, .net, file, exception, task-parallel-library

I am unzipping a.gz files by using the following code.Since i have huge number of files , I am using TPL tasks to run this code. But I used to get `.NET` exception:

> The process cannot access the file  because it is being used by another process.

How to correct this issue?
Code used is as follows:

```
private static void Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
{
    using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
    {
        string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
        string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - 
                                          fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);
        using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
        {
            using (GZipStream decompressionStream = 
                     new GZipStream(originalFileStream, 
                                    CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
            }
        }
    }
    //File.Move(myffile, Path.ChangeExtension(myffile, ".jpg"));
}
```

calling code is as shown below

```
var list = ftp.GetFileList(remotepath);

//-------------------
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string st = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", dt);//20161120
Task[] myTasks = new Task[list.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach (string item in list)
{
     if (item.StartsWith("GExport_") && (!item.ToUpper().Contains("DUM")) && (item.Contains(st)) && (!item.ToUpper().Contains("BLK")))
     {
         4gpath = item;
        //Downloadfile()   
        ftp.Get(dtr["REMOTE_FILE_PATH"].ToString() + 4gpath , @localDestnDir + "\\" + dtr["SOURCE_PATH"].ToString());
        download_location_hw = dtr["LOCAL_FILE_PATH"].ToString();
        // Spin off a background task to process the file we just downloaded
        myTasks[i++] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Extractfile()             
            ExtractZipfiles(download_location_hw + "//" + huwawei4gpath, dtr["REMOTE_FILE_PATH"].ToString(), 
             dtr["FTP_SERVER"].ToString(), dtr["FTP_USER_ID"].ToString(),
             dtr["TECH_CODE"].ToString(), dtr["VENDOR_CODE"].ToString());
        }
    }
}

private static void ExtractZipfiles(string download_location_hw,string remotepath,string server,string userid,string tech,string vendor)
{
    if (download_location_hw.Contains(".gz"))
    {
        DirectoryInfo directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(download_location_hw));
        foreach (FileInfo fileToDecompress in directorySelected.GetFiles("*.gz"))
        {
            Decompress(fileToDecompress);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code calling this method?  Particularly the _TPL_ bits

Comment: i posted calling code

Comment: What's use of `myTasks`?

Comment: to dowload and unizipp large number of files faster way

Answer (score 2):

You're possibly extracting the `zip` files downloaded bu your tasks in the same folder:

```
download_location_hw = dtr["LOCAL_FILE_PATH"].ToString();
var directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(download_location_hw));
```

If for somethat reason you have two files being targeted to the same local path, final `foreach` statement will have intersections with other tasks:

```
foreach (var fileToDecompress in directorySelected.GetFiles("*.gz"))
{
    Decompress(fileToDecompress);
}
```

Here you're searching for all `*.gz` files in folder, even those ones that can be still in download mode or being decompressed by other process. So you should be definitely sure each tasks is being run in the different folder.

If you want to simple correction of your code, you may try this (the main change here is not to enumerate all the archive files but simply get one from the task arguments, with [`FileInfo` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx)):

```
private static void ExtractZipfiles(string download_location_hw,string remotepath,string server,string userid,string tech,string vendor)
{
    if (download_location_hw.Contains(".gz") && File.Exists(download_location_hw))
    {
        Decompress(new FileInfo(download_location_hw));
    }
}
```

Comment: Each task corresponds to one file?

Comment: @peter updated the answer. You should not ask the same question again and again

Answer (score 1):

The various tasks are operating on the same download path and are causing a collission.
For eg. Task 1 puts a.gz, b.gz while Task 2 puts c.gz under "MyDir".

But now both tasks are operating and trying to rename the files to *a, b, c* during decompression. So, it appears you need to create subdirectories for each of the tasks or prefix\suffix the file names that are downloaded with unique identifiers.

Comment: The parallel tasks you are launching are working on all files instead of working on only the files that they're downloading.